# What waked up my computer?

Tags: 64-bit, 13.10, suspend

I want to know if there is a command or program that shows the reason of the last wakeup from suspend.

In windows exists a builtin command which shows the last wakeup reason, for example the keyboard or mouse, or via WOL.

The thing is that it happened already 2 times to find my computer awake in the morning when I clearly put it to sleep at night.

/var/log/pm-suspend.log:

> Tue Oct 22 23:50:24 EEST 2013: performing suspend
>   Wed Oct 23 08:24:11 EEST 2013: Awake.
>   Wed Oct 23 08:24:11 EEST 2013: Running hooks for resume

[/var/log/syslog](http://pastebin.com/Umy34rYV)

[dmesg](http://pastebin.com/sNT1eLY5)

PS: Default 13.10 installation, WOL enabled, but I don't think this is a problem since I used WOL before (with Archlinux and SuSe) and it only woke when I told it to do so.

Comment: Not sure if the required information will be logged, but you could try setting `PM_DEBUG="true"` to get detailed output in `pm-suspend.log`. You can set this variable in any file in `/etc/pm/config.d`. Create one if there isn't, making sure it is `chmod +x`. Don't forget to unset afterwards.

Comment: `hwinfo` should tell you.

Comment: I can't install hwinfo:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package hwinfo is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hwinfo' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating more, the fault was caused by my wireless mouse. If I put the computer into sleep and then moved the mouse, the computer would wake.

The solution was adding `echo "disabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7/power/wakeup` in `/etc/rc.local` for it to run every time I power my computer.

That tells the usb port on which I have my EDR transmitter to disable the option of waking up via mouse.

Simple and clean.

Comment: and how did you discover it?

Comment: I did a `lsusb` first, then `grep "name" /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product` and I see the 3-7 part.

For example, I want to search for Microsoft Nano Transceiver, I do `grep "Microsoft Nano Transceiver" /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product` and get `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/product:Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1`.

I then write disabled in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/wakeup`

Comment: For anyone checking this answer out now (2022), you may be able to run `lsusb -v` to get a similar, full-path output for each usb device as what @big_bum proposed without having to guess at the product name.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, somehow it was a faulty website running a script in my browser, resulting in waking the computer.

I will leave this unsolved since I didn't find a program to answer my question.

Comment: So, closing the browser solved the issue?

Comment: The browser or the site.

Comment: Either of them?

Comment: Yes, either of them. The browser or the site.
Since I leave my browser open all the time, I closed the tab in which the faulty site was opened and the problem with waking up disapeared.
I still haven't found a program to tell what exactly waked my computer, though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Please approve [your own accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/383523/283843)

Comment: @Pabi Yes it does answer the question. Read it again :)